# access the response Json data in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, ajax

I'm using a Json in my HTML to get data from Database but I can't access the data of returned Json here is my HTML function :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'fetch.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {func:"viewCert",tracking_code:tracking_code},
    success: function (data) {
        if (data!=null) {
            document.getElementById("generation_date").textContent = data.certInfo.timestamp;
        } else {
            alert("Something's Wrong! Try Later");
            window.location = "../views/failed.html";
        }
    }
});
```

and here is fetch.php function :

```
function viewCert($tracking_code) {
    $connect = connection();
     $connect->set_charset("utf8");
    $sql = "SELECT timestamp FROM certificate WHERE tracking_code=?";
    $result = $connect->prepare($sql);
    $result->bind_param("s",$tracking_code);
    $result->execute();
    $res=$result->get_result();
    while ($row=$res->fetch_object()) {
        $output[]=$row;
    }
    echo json_encode(array('certInfo' => $output));
}
```

Sorry for this question I'm just new in HTML and Javascript , so anyone know why timestamp won't be set in 'generation_date' element?
any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Use `console.log(data)` after `success: function (data) {` and show us the result ? Also show generation_date element.

Comment: I think $output is an array, maybe you need to access with an index to the desired value ? like `data.certInfo[0].timestamp`

Comment: have you tried doing. `$.parseJSON(data)` ?

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm sorry where the Log prints? in inspect part of browser?

Comment: @ShakibKarami press f12  to show the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP, `$output` seems to be an array. So in your javascript you need to access on the good index to get the data.

Try :

```
 document.getElementById("generation_date").textContent = data.certInfo[0].timestamp;
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------^^^
```

Comment: @ShakibKarami Like MorganFreeFarm comment, we need the content of `consol.log(data)` at the start of the success function to help you

Comment: sorry I was wrong certInfo was an array :) thanks a lot for your help